# Subscription form won't send information to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert, subscribe

I have a subscription form with just two text boxes for name and email. I want those information to be stored in the MySql database. When submitting the form, I can connect to the database, but the information are not sent. This is the code for the form (just the interested part):

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Community Garden</h1>
  <p>We are a local community that
  grows organic vegetables and fruit</p>
  <img src="Front.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="front" > <br><br>
  <form class="form-inline" action="news.php" method="post'>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Name" required> 
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
     <br><br> <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is the php script for the database connection and storing of information. This file is called news.php.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
//include database connection details
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("Community Garden List",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//collect data from form and remove any tags and make safe for database entry
$name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));

//check name lengh
if (strlen($name) < 3) {
    $error[] = 'Name must be more then 3 characters.';
}

//if name is equal to name then give an error
if ($name == 'Name') {
    $error[] = 'Please enter your name.';
}

// check for valid email address
$error = "";
$pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if (!preg_match($pattern, trim($email))) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

// if validation is okay then carry on
if (!$error ) {

//insert into database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')")or die(mysql_error());

//submission successful show a message
echo "<p>Thank you, submission was successful.</p>";

} // end validation
}// end submit

//show any errors
if (!empty($error))
{
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($error)){
        echo '<div class="msg-error">".$error[$i]."</div>';
        $i ++;}
}// close if empty errors

?>
```

Comment: Your regex for email validation would allow `.%@..com` but break on any valid tld which is over 4 chars, which there are many.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your opening `<form>` tag is malformed?

Specifically the method part:

```
 method="post'
```

See how the opening quote is double but the closing one is single. The W3C validator fails to validate such a form tag. Considering this, the browser might be ignoring this attribute and submit your form with the default method, which is GET. (Or it might just be completely ignoring the `<form>`.)

You can validate your HTML here: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're basically not running `$sql`. In order to insert in database you should delete `$sql=` part.
In your code, you're just using the `$sql` variable to store your query.